# An easily refreshable Queue for Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I would like to find a mechanism to easily report the progress of a Python thread.  For example, if my thread had a counter, I would like to know the value of the counter once in awhile, but, importantly, I only need to know the latest value, not every value that's ever gone by.

What I imagine to be the simplest solution is a single value Queue, where every time I `put` a new value on in the thread, it replaces the old value with the new one.  Then when I do a `get` in the main program, it would only return the latest value.

Because I don't know how to do the above, instead what I do is `put` every counter value in a queue, and when I `get`, I get all the values until there are no more, and just keep the last.  But this seems far from ideal, in that I'm filling the queues with thousands of values the I don't care about.

Here's an example of what I do now:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from time import sleep

N = 1000

def fast(q):
    count = 0
    while count<N:
        sleep(.02)
        count += 1
        q.put(count)

def slow(q):
    while 1:
        sleep(5)  # sleep for a long time
        # read last item in queue
        val = None
        while 1:  # read all elements of queue, only saving last
            try:
                val = q.get(block=False)
            except Empty:
                break
        print val   # the last element read from the queue
        if val==N:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    q = Queue()
    fast_thread = Thread(target=fast, args=(q,))
    fast_thread.start()
    slow(q)
    fast_thread.join()
```

My question is, is there a better approach?

Comment: im not quite sure why you don't just use a shared variable? as long as only one thread writes and all other read, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you just make a `Queue` with `maxsize=1`?

Comment: I'm with @DonQuestion here. Why not just access `count` directly inside of `slow`?

Comment: @DonQuestion: could you write this as an answer?  That way others and I can comment on it.  Basically though, I have been unsure about the rules here, so you imply if I only have one writer, the reader will never have problems?  Is there a docs reference to this issue?

Comment: @ap: using `maxsize=1` will block after the first value I put in.  I want it to allow me to continue to update and only keep the latest value.

Comment: @tom10: There's a ton of literature regarding this problem. It's never (ok, almost never) the reading, only the writing, that causes headaches, if more then one concurrent process try to access the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a global variable and a `threading.Lock` to protect it during assignments:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

N = 1000
value = 0
def fast(lock):
    global value
    count = 0
    while count<N:
        sleep(.02)
        count += 1
        with lock:
            value = count

def slow():
    while 1:
        sleep(5)  # sleep for a long time
        print value   # read current value
        if value == N:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    lock = threading.Lock()
    fast_thread = threading.Thread(target=fast, args=(lock,))
    fast_thread.start()
    slow()
    fast_thread.join()
```

yields (something like)

```
249
498
747
997
1000
```

As Don Question points out, if there is only one thread modifying `value`, then
actually no lock is needed in the `fast` function. And as dano points out, if you want to
ensure that the value printed in `slow` is the same value used in the
`if-statement`, then a lock is needed in the `slow` function.

For more on when locks are needed, see [Thread Synchronization Mechanisms in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm).

Comment: why do you need a lock in this example? only one thread (as by op) actually writes to `value`.

Comment: I'm not really sure a lock is needed here, unless you want to make sure `value` hasn't changed between the time you print it and the time you do `if value == N`. If that's the behavior you're going for, you're not actually getting it since you're not acquiring `lock` inside of `slow`.

Comment: @DonQuestion: You're right; if there is only one thread writing to value, then a lock is not needed. But in general, if more than one thread could assign to `value`, you'll need a lock.

Comment: @unutbu: yes, i concur completely

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Although all the answers are good, this is the one I'm going with, mostly because of it's clarity and flexibility, and that the behavior is well documented.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) with a maximum length of 1.  It will just keep your latest value.

So, instead of:

```
q = Queue()
```

use:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque(maxlen=1)
```

To read from the deque, there's no `get` method, so you'll have to do something like:

```
val = None
try:
    val = q[0]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: Is `deque` thread safe?  I thought I had to stick with Queue structures because they had the appropriate locking mechanisms built-in.

Comment: @msvalkon: What do you mean its not entirely thread safe?  The docs say: "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems to be an equally good answer to my exact question, but in the end I wanted something a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

In your special case, you may over-complicate the issue. If your variable is just some kind of progress-indenticator of a single thread, and only this thread actually changes the variable, then it's completely safe to use a shared object to communicate the progress as long as all other threads do only read.

I guess we all read to many (rightfully) warnings about race-conditions and other pitfalls of shared states in concurrent programming, so we tend to overthink and add more precaution then is sometimes needed.

You could basically share a pre-constructed dict:

```
thread_progress = dict.fromkeys(list_of_threads, progress_start_value)
```

or manually:

```
thread_progress = {thread: progress_value, ...}
```

without further precaution as long as no thread changes the dict-keys.

This way you can track the progress of multiple threads over one dict. Only condition is to not change the dict once the threading started. Which means the dict must contain **all** threads **BEFORE** the first **child-thread starts**, else you must use a Lock, before writing to the dict. With "changing the dict" i mean all operation regarding the keys. You may change the associated values of a key, because that's in the next level of indirection.

**Update**:

The underlying problem is the shared state. Which is already a problem in linear Programs, but a nightmare in concurrent.

For example: Imagine a global (shared) variable `sv` and two functions `G(ood)` and `B(ad)` in a linear program. Both function calculate a result depending on `sv`, but `B` unintentionally changes `sv`. Now you are wondering why the heck `G` doesn't do what it should do, despite not finding any error in your function `G`, even after you tested it isolated and it was perfectly fine.

Now imagine the same scenario in a concurrent program, with two Threads `A` and `B`. Both Threads increment the shared state/variable `sv` by one.

without locking (current value of `sv` in parenthesis):

```
sv = 0
A reads sv  (0)
B reads sv  (0)
A inc sv    (0)
B inc sv    (0)
A writes sv (1)
B writes sv (1) 
sv == 1 # should be 2!
```

To find the source of the problem is a pure nightmare! Because it could also succeed sometimes. More often than not `A` actually would succeed to finish, before `B` even starts to read `sv`, but now your problem just seems to behave non-deterministic or erratic and is even harder to find. In contrast to my linear example, both threads are "good", but nevertheless behave not as intentioned.

with locking:

```
sv = 0
l = lock (for access on sv)
A tries to aquire lock for sv -> success (0)
B tries to aquire lock for sv -> failure, blocked by A (0)
A reads sv  (0)
B blocked (0)
A inc sv    (0)
B blocked    (0)
A writes sv (1)
B blocked (1)
A releases lock on sv (1)
B tries to aquire lock for sv -> success (1)
...
sv == 2
```

I hope my little example explained the underlying problem of accessing a shared state and
why making write operations (including the read operation) atomic through locking is necessary.

Regarding my advice of a pre-initialized dict: This is a mere precaution because of two reasons:

1. if you iterate over the threads in a for-loop, the loop may raise an
   exception if a thread adds or removes an entry to/from the dict
   while still in the loop, because it now is unclear what the next key
   should be.
2. Thread A reads the dict and gets interrupted by Thread B which adds
   an entry and finishes. Thread A resumes, but doesn't have the dict
   Thread B changed and writes the pre-B together with it's own changes
   back. Thread Bs changes are lost.

BTW my proposed solution wouldn't work atm, because of the immutability of the primitive types. But this could be easily fixed by making them mutable, e.g. by encapsulating them into a list or an special Progress-Object, or even simpler: give the thread-function access to the `thread_progress` dict .

Explanation by example:

```
t = Thread()
progress = 0        # progress points to the object `0`
dict[t] = progress  # dict[t] points now to object `0`
progress = 1        # progress points to object `1`
dict[t]             # dict[t] still points to object `0`
```

better:

```
t = Thread()
t.progress = 0        
dict[thread_id] = t   
t.progress = 1        
dict[thread_id].progress == 1
```

Comment: This was all very interesting and I appreciate the idea.  I had trouble finding the right documentation.  As I understand, the key word seems to be "atomic", in that in Python, atomic operations are thread safe.  But I found it difficult to get the details on this, for example, the points you make about dictionaries, and when I can add keys, etc.

Comment: I did an update, hoping to address the questions of your comment.